# How row_number() works?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was searching removing duplicate entries on a table and I saw an example like below:

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers
(
  Id int identity (1,1),
  CompanyTitle nvarchar(1000),
  ContactName nvarchar(100),
  LastContactDate datetime
)

INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Melody Music Instruments',N'James Manning', '20090623 10:15')
INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Blue Jazz',N'Mike Clark', '20090720 15:40')
INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Top Music',N'Katy Swan', '20090827 18:00')
INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Blue Jazz',N'Mike Clark', '20090806 10:00')
INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Melody Music Instruments',N'James Brown', '20080121 11:20')
INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Top Music',N'Katy Perry', '20090825 14:00')
INSERT Suppliers VALUES (N'Top Music',N'Katy Perry', '20090825 14:00')


WITH Duplicate AS 
(
SELECT
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyTitle ORDER BY LastContactDate DESC)
FROM Suppliers
)
delete from Duplicate where RN > 1
```

CTE returns something like and then I delete if the value is greater than 1.

```
RN
--
1
2
1
2
1
2
3
```

What I didnt understand is how it understands which entry will be deleted. It just returns dublicate entry count by this example.

Live example : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d84b6/20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example table is a heap (meaning it has no clustered index).

If you look at the execution plan for your example you will see that `Bmk1000` is in the output column list for the leaf level table scan and that this column is passed along across all the operators in the plan up until the `DELETE` operator.

`Bmk1000` is a bookmark that uniquely identifies where the row will be found (The row identifier for a heap contains the location of the row's File:Page:Slot) so this can be used by the `DELETE` operator to locate the required row.

If your table had a clustered index you would likely see that the clustered index key column(s) were passed along in this manner instead of the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

What is your question?  It is deleting anything where the row number is greater than 1 . . . the code is quite explicit `RN > 1`.

It is assigning the row numbers to the rows, starting over with each CompanyTitle.  The row with the most recent contact date gets the value of 1.

So, this code is deleting everything older than the most recent contact for each CompanyTitle.

Comment: I think that he/she wants to know how the DELETE knows which rows in the physical Table, correspond to those rows to delete in the derived table, since it is only passing the RN column, without any key information.

Comment: @RBarryYoung . . . So the answer is "you can add a calculated column in a query and SQL can use it in a `where` clause"?

Comment: Well, you're answering, not me Gordon.  :-)  I'm just explaining what I think the question meant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how key information is kept by the derived table ? Which topic should I read to understand this in dept ?

Comment: @Ryu . . . Your question is very specific.  It sounds like you want to know about execution plans.  Start with the documentation . . . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx.  This is a very intense subject, though.  The easiest answer "pretend like an intermediate table is made" isn't true and doesn't work for `delete`.  The more complicated answer is that the engine keeps some  sort of record identifier, but that is only the beginning of how it works.

Comment: I started to understand the way how SQL works. +1 for helping me to clarifying things. I keep open this topic to except more answer for a little time

Answer (score 1):

The PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clauses control which rows will be deleted.  It's more obvious how this works if you expand the CTE a little bit. (PostgreSQL syntax)

```
WITH Duplicate AS 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyTitle ORDER BY LastContactDate DESC),
    CompanyTitle, 
    LastContactDate 
  FROM Suppliers
)
select * 
from Duplicate
```

(Blank lines added below for readability.)

```
1  Blue Jazz                    2009-08-06 10:00:00
2  Blue Jazz                    2009-07-20 15:40:00

1  Melody Music Instruments     2009-06-23 10:15:00
2  Melody Music Instruments     2008-01-21 11:20:00

1  Top Music                    2009-08-27 18:00:00
2  Top Music                    2009-08-25 14:00:00
3  Top Music                    2009-08-25 14:00:00
```

The PARTITION clause keeps identical CompanyTitle values together. The ORDER BY clause sorts rows that have the *same* value for CompanyTitle by LastContactDate.  Since it sorts descending, the most recent row for each CompanyTitle will always be numbered 1.

So to delete all the rows *except* the most recent one for each CompanyTitle, you delete all the rows that have a row number greater than 1.